# Cannot connect to remote mysql through tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I am able to connect to mysql through a gui workbench but when i try to connect with my applications datasource (which runs on tomcat) i get:

```
Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'192.168.100.231' (using password: YES)
```

i have tried all the options in the mysql reference guide but none worked.
any ideas?

Comment: What does your grant table look like, for dbuser?

Comment: Are the GUI workbench and the tomcat on the same machine? Did you check the password in tomcat?

Comment: @Vivien yes and yes, the password is right

Comment: @James the grant table:  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dbuser'@'192.168.100.231' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: Can you post the connection code and/or pool setup.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i dropped the user and redefined it and then all worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should grant access to remote machine. Connect to MySql as root and do this:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Instead of IP you may use host you remote machine.